# calling this.hide() exits application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

I have a main form that starts when an application runs:

```
Application.Run(new MainMenu());
```

My main form looks like this:

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{
    Authentication auth;
    public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.auth = new Authentication();
    }

    private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!auth.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            auth.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

My authentication method runs the following when authentication is verified:

```
this.Hide();
```

But this causes the application to exit completely. Any idea why?
I thought that because I have run auth.ShowDialog(), this is a modal form that when running this.Hide() should close this form to expost the main form again?

Comment: Can you confirm this is Windows Mobile? If so, what version?

Comment: Windows Mobile itself is a dead-end platform, and 6.5 is now over 3 years old and the .NET Compact Framework has been frozen in time for over 5 years now (because WP7x uses Silverlight's CLR instead). It isn't hard to develop for, but I have questions about the business-case here.

Comment: To help you further, I need you to post the code where `this.Hide()` is being called. It isn't clear what object `this` is referring to.

Comment: Are you sure the application exited?  Maybe it is running and you can't see it because you actually hid the main form.

Comment: OK so I fixed it by chaning this.Hide() to this.Close(). Any ideas why?

Comment: Something isn't right. Calling **Authentication** using `ShowDialog()` should not allow you to call `this.Hide()` or `this.Close()` on your main form, as the **Authentication** form will be modal (have focus).

Comment: Hi. I am not calling it on the main form- I am calling it on the Authentication form that shows (I want to hide this form once authenticated to expose the main form)